# Angular: How to push labels from multiple objects containing array too?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to push a **single value from multiple objects** here is the output of it [image]

Here is my code:

```js
 this.ExportprintData = [];
      var chartLabels = this.chartLabelsAll;
      // this.ExportprintData.push(" ");
      for (var i = 0; i < this.chartLabelsAll; i++) {
        chartLabels.push({ 'Labels': this.chartLabelsAll[i] });
      }
      this.ExportprintData[0] = chartLabels;
      if (this.chartLabelsAll[0] != "") {
        this.ExportprintData[0].unshift("");
        this.chartLabelsAll.splice(0, 1);
      }

     
       this.exportExceldata = this.AVEChartDataAVE; console.log(this.AVEChartDataAll);
```

**expected output**
But I need to print an array of labels only like this

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @MichaelD second image is what I am expecting to print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array `map` function can do it for you.

Like below:

```js
var jsonArray = [
  {label: 'Label 1', data: ['1']},
  {label: 'Label 2', data: ['1']},
  {label: 'Label 3', data: ['1']},
  {label: 'Label 4', data: ['1']},
  {label: 'Label 5', data: ['1']}
];

var tempArray = jsonArray.map((item) => item.label);
console.log(tempArray);
```

This should do your work

Answer (score 0):

You could use Array `map` method to generate an array of strings from the object array.

```js
let chartLabels = this.chartLabelsAll.map(info => info.label);
```